# Button fill inside grid column in Windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am new to Windows Phone development. I created a grid and added a button to one of the columns, the button does not fill the entire grid column. I am not even able to drag and resize the button control.

This is the code. The button appears at the center of column 0 and is cropped since it tries to fill into column2 as well. The same code seems to work fine in a 8.0 project I downloaded. Can anyone tell me how I can make the button fill the entire column and not spill into the second grid.

Updated code

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>        
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">Text</Button>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">Text</Button>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">Text</Button>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3">Text</Button>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this to your `Button`.

```
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
```

In WP8.1, its default value is `Left`.

**Update**

The cut-off issue is because there's a default `MinWidth` (109) set to the default `Button` style.

Try removing it by doing this.

```
MinWidth="0"
```

Comment: Tried. I see no difference.

Comment: You will also need to allow enough space in your columns. Do this `<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>`.

Comment: Adding <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/> and  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" produced the intended result. There is a new issue though. My goal was to have four buttons of equal size in each of the four columns. How can I go about achieving that? Right now the last button is pushed out of view by the other 3 buttons.

Comment: If that's the case don't you need to reduce the size of your `Buttons`?? So you should change back the column definition to what it was, and try to make each of your buttons smaller.

Comment: How can I do that? I read hard coding width and size of buttons will make it unscalable to larger resolutions.

Comment: You need to update your question with the full xaml code of your buttons.

Comment: If I use a textblock instead of a button it works fine. Something is going on in the way the button is drawn in 8.1. I just cannot understand what.

Comment: That fixed it. Awesome. Can you explain how setting the min width resulted in the correct output? How come this was not needed if I use a textblock instead?

Comment: See my updated answer. `TextBlock` doesn't have a `MinWidth` by default. It basically means, the `Button` at least needs to have that much width (109). But then 109 is more than what each column has. Make sense?

Comment: Yes. Thanks again for the help. This has been driving me mad for 2 days.